# How do I set up and solve this recurrence relation for this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

```
Recursive R(n)
if n==1 return 1;
else return R(n-1)+n*n*n
```

How do I set up and solve this recurrence relation for this algorithm (sum of n cubes)?

Comment: If n==1 return **what**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denoting `S(n)` the sum of the first `n` cubes, `S(n)` must be a polynomial of the fourth degree in `n`, let

```
S(n) = an^4+bn³+cn²+dn.
```

This is because

1) `S(0)= 0`, so there is no independent term,

2) When computing `S(n)-S(n-1)`, which must equal `n³`, you get a polynomial of the third degree, by cancellation of the quartic term:

```
S(n)-S(n-1) = a(n^4-(n-1)^4)+b(n³-(n-1)³)+c(n²-(n-1)²)+d(n-(n-1)).
```

Developing and simplifying,

```
a(4n³-6n²+4n-1)+b(3n²-3n+1)+c(2n-1)+d = n³.
```

Let us identify the coefficients:

```
n³:  4a        =1
n²: -6a+3b     =0
n:   4a-3b+2c  =0
1:   -a +b -c+d=0
```

Solving this triangular system is straigthforward:

```
a=1/4
b=1/2
c=1/4
d=0.
```

and finally

```
S(n) = (n^4+2n³+n²)/4 = n²(n+1)²/4.
```

It can be simpler to use the [Faulhaber formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Examples), or just consider that a sum is like an integral and the sum of `n³` is approximately `n^4/4`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if n == 1 you should probably return 1. And yes, this recursive function computes 1 + 2^3 + 3^3 + ... + n^3. How do we know that?

Well, take an example like n = 5;

- R(5) returns R(4) + 5^3
- R(4) returns R(3) + 4^3
- ....
- R(2) returns R(1) + 2^3
- R(1) returns 1

If you add them up => R(5) returns 5^3 + 4^3 + .. + 2^3 + 1.